# Scope data seem empty after putting json in it

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get some data from an API in the variable $scope.proposition with the following code

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('propositionCtrl',['$scope', 'propositionRepository',
    function ($scope, propositionRepository) {
       // $scope.proposition = { marge_propose: 3 };
        function getProposition() {
            propositionRepository.getProposition(function (result) {
                $scope.proposition = result;
                console.log("we put the json in the scope variable");
            }
            )
        }
        getProposition();
        $scope.proposition = {marge_propose : 3};
    }])

app.factory('propositionRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        getProposition: function (callback) {
            $http.get('/api/propositionapi/3');
            console.log("we call the api");
        }
    }
})
```

With the following view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div ng-controller="propositionCtrl">

    <p>{{ proposition.marge_propose}}</p>


</div>
```

It does not work, but when I uncomment the `$scope.proposition = { marge_propose: 3 };` everything works just fine.

That's why I assume that it is my getProposition that encounters some problems.

I don't know what it is because firebug actually tells me that the data are well received from the api with the following result

```
{"$id":"1","t_concours":{"$id":"2","t_proposition":[{"$ref":"1"}],"id":1,"intitule":"test","valeur":10.0},"t_demandeur":{"$id":"3","t_proposition":[{"$ref":"1"}],"id":"1","nom":"dylan","prenom":"bob","note":"A"},"t_index":{"$id":"4","t_proposition":[{"$ref":"1"}],"id":1,"intitule":"test","valeur":10.0},"t_proposition_concurence":null,"id":3,"id_demandeur":"1","date_proposition":"1991-07-05T00:00:00","type":true,"point_de_vente":"01","code":"a","code_sas":"846684","montant_operation_hors_frais":200,"concours_sollicite":10,"duree_concours":10,"type_concours":1,"id_index":1,"apport_personnel":10,"garantie_reelle":true,"in_fine":false,"majoration":1.0,"prospect":true,"primo_accedant":true,"motif_montant":false,"motif_contrepartie":false,"motif_depot_cmne":false,"id_prop_concurence":null,"motif_autre":true,"motif_commentaire":"true","proposition_derogatoire":true,"visa_responsable":"false","marge_grille":5.0,"marge_theorique":7.0,"marge_propose":32.0}
```

Can someone explain me please where the problem is?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

The console log displays "we call the api" but not "we put the json in the scope variable"

Comment: Move your getProposition(); after function getProposition()

Comment: I've done it, doesn't change a thing =) Thanks anyway!

Comment: console.log(callback); it will be null right ? if true that is because the $http service returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the extra data as real JSON, eg:

```
$scope.proposition = { "marge_propose": "3" };
```

maybe try to console.log in your propositionRepository to view the result you're getting, place a console.log in the getProposition() as well to check if everything is passing trough fine

EDIT:
here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c1zxp6uo/

bottomline: you don't call the callback, so when you do

`$http.get('/api/propositionapi/3').then(function(){callback()})`

it should work

Comment: Thanks.
I've updated my quetion with new information thanks to your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('propositionCtrl',['$scope', 'propositionRepository',
    function ($scope, propositionRepository) {
       // $scope.proposition = { marge_propose: 3 };
        function getProposition() {
            propositionRepository.getProposition(function (result) {
                console.log("we put the json in the scope variable");
                $scope.proposition = result;

            }
            )
        }
        getProposition();

        $scope.proposition = {marge_propose : 3};
    }])

app.factory('propositionRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        getProposition: function (callback) {
            $http.get('/api/propositionapi/3').success(callback);
            console.log("we call the api");
        }
    }
})
```

This code works...

The thing is that I didn't know that $http.get returns a promise, so I forgot to add the `.success(callback)` in the line

```
$http.get('/api/propositionapi/3').success(callback);
```

Now everthing works.

Thanks for the hint MohammedAbbas